# How to get an inverse value based on another value

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I am not a math wiz, so this may be trivial for some.

What is the best formula for the following:

Say you have $x$ and $y$, where $y$ is a value from $0$ to $20$.

As $x$ goes from $0$ to $100$, $y$ should go from $20$ to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have two points on your line. You know the $y$ value when $x$ is $0$, and when $x$ is $100$. Do you have a formula for the equation of a line given two points on it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic linear interpolation from $z_1$ to $z_2$ parameterized by $t$ going from $0$ to $1$:

$$
z = (1-t) z_1 + t z_2
$$

This gives for interpolaton of $x$ from $0$ to $100$:
$$
x = (1-t) 0 + t\, 100  = t \,100 \iff t = \frac{x}{100}
$$
Then use that $t$ in the interpolation for $y$ from $20$ to $0$:
$$
y = \left(1-\frac{x}{100}\right) \,20 + \frac{x}{100}\, 0 
= \left(1-\frac{x}{100}\right)\,20 = 20 - \frac{x}{5}
$$
Of course, if you have a bit experience you will be able to guess it right from the start.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question but could you be looking for a function like $y(x) = \frac{100-x}{5}$?